# How to append some data into existing xlsx sheet R?

Tags: r, data-science, xlsx, xlsxwriter, xlconnect

I´m trying to read a xlsx file and write one data frame into the same sheet of xlsx without remove the other rows of my data frame.

I tried with the `library("XLConnect")` and with the function appendWorksheet() but the data is not writing in the correct place, and with the `library("xlsx")` but I can´t find a function similar to appendWorksheet.

I just want to read my xlsx file and write my data that is into a data frame and write into the same xlsx file without removing the previous rows.

Answer (score 0):

There doesn't seem to be a great way to append data to an xlsx file. You can create a function which will read in the sheet and append data to the dataframe and then overwrite the xlsx.

```
library(xslx)
appendxlsx <- function(df2, path, sheetName) {
  df1 <- read.xlsx2(path, sheetName = sheetName)
  colnames(df2) <- colnames(df1)
  df <- rbind(df1, df2)
  write.xlsx2(df, path, sheetName = sheetName)
}
```

Then you would just call the function supplying the updated dataframe (df2), the path to the xlsx, and the sheet name. Something like this:

```
appendxlsx(df2=df2, "/path/to/xlsx", sheetName = "Sheet1")
```